# How to get filteredData in react-data-table-component-with-filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-table-component

I am using `react-data-table-component-with-filter` lib for data table, additionaly I have included export to excel functionality; now I want only filtered data for the excel.
Any suggestions how I can archive this.

```
import { useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component-with-filter";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
import users from "./users";

const App = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState(users);
const columns = useCallback([
    {
    name: "Name",
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selector: (row) => row.name,
    },
    {
    name: "Email",
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selector: (row) => row.email,
    },
]);

const actionExport = useMemo(() => {
    const exportToXlsx = (data) => {
    let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    let ws1 = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws1, "React Table Data");
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, `test.xlsx`);
    return false;
    };

    return (
    <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
        <input type="date" className="form-control" />
        <button className="btn shrink-0" onClick={() => exportPdf(data)}>
        Bulk PDF
        </button>
        <button className="btn shrink-0" onClick={() => exportToXlsx(data)}>
        Download XLSX
        </button>
    </div>
    );
});
return (
    <DataTable
    title="Doctors List"
    pagination
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    persistTableHead
    actions={actionExport}
    />
);
};
export default App;
```

`